# Indexing Systems of Equations in GAMS

Tags: equation, gams-math

I wanna define a set of indexing equation in GAMS as the following picture. But some errors occur at the term of (A(3-i)-A(i)). 
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Be3-4R8EyCpBaCI8X5LXB1WsRT3IbcD1)

Comment: What do you want to achieve when you write `A(3-i)` in that equation? In general, chances are probably higher to get some help here, if you post your code directly and describe what kind of error you get.

Comment: Set i Index of components /1*2/;
Parameters A(i) Margules Coefficients
/1 1.0
2 2.0/;
Parameters x(i) Composition
/1 0.25
2 0.75/;

Variables ac(i) Activity coefficient of the i-th component
          J     The objective value;

Equations obj  The objective function
          act(i)  The activity equation of the i-th component;

obj..         J=e=0;
act(i).. ac(i)=e=system.exp(power((1-x(i)), 2) * (A(i)+2*x(i)*(A(3-i)-A(i))));

Comment: I write A(3-i) to achieve the A(2) when i is equal 2 and A(1) when i is equal to 2.
in other words, ac(1) is a function of  (A(2)-A(1)) and ac(2) is a function of (A(1)-A(2))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
act(i).. ac(i)=e=system.exp(power((1-x(i)), 2) * (A(i)+2*x(i)*(A(i+[card(i)+1-2*ord(i)])-A(i))));
```